# what is the factory for url rewrites?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

If you want to create url rewrites programmatically what factory should you use?

Tried a few of them but none have the right methods (like `setStoreId`, `save`, `setTargetPath` and `setRequestPath`):

`Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory` or `Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewriteFactory` or
`Magento/UrlRewrite/Service/V1/Data/UrlRewriteFactory` (missing save method)

Thanks!

**Update:**
If these are the only factories available how does one save a rewrite?

For example if you use `Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory` there is no save method:

```
$urlRewriteModel = $this->urlRewriteFactory->create();
$urlRewriteModel->setStoreId($storeId);
$urlRewriteModel->setTargetPath("yes");
$urlRewriteModel->setRequestPath("yes2");
$urlRewriteModel->save(); //this fails with no save method
```

**Update2**:

Thanks for the help, the final solution looks like this:
https://github.com/ClaudiuCreanga/magento2-store-locator-stockists-extension/blob/master/src/Model/UrlRewrite.php#L139

Comment: `Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory <= Data abstract class for url storage`, we cannot use this class to create the url rewrite. We should use `Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/CanonicalUrlRewriteGenerator.php**

```
        /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory */
         protected $urlRewriteFactory;

           $this->urlRewriteFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setEntityType(CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE)
                ->setEntityId($category->getId())
                ->setRequestPath($urlPath)
                ->setTargetPath($this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getCanonicalUrlPath($category))
```

These classes are auto-generate factory classes, we can find them under `var/generation` folder:

```
Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory <= Model class
Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewriteFactory <= Resource Model
Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory <= Data abstract class for url storage
```

Shortly, these factory classes create the object instance of themselves.

We can read more [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75643/magento2-factory-pattern-advantages-over-magento1) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/difference-between-factory-vs-objectmanager-while-instance-object).

**An example - Create the url rewrites programmatically:**

We should use `\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory`

```
 /** @var $rewrite \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory */

$rewrite->setStoreId(
    1
)->setIdPath(
    'product/1/4'
)->setRequestPath(
    'category-2/simple-product.html'
)->setTargetPath(
    'catalog/product/view/id/1'
)->setIsSystem(
    1
)->setCategoryId(
    4
)->setProductId(
    1
)->save();
```

Comment: thanks, it explains how I can find factories when I need them, but still I don't understand why there is no save method in `Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewriteFactory`